# cx-freeze executable not working with virtualenv

Tags: python, matplotlib, virtualenv, cx-freeze

I have setup a virtual environment (Python 3.5) for a small cx-freeze (5.0.2) test. But the created executable does not run. However, the py-script itself is working correctly in the virtual environment.

This is the script that I want to compile into an exe
[3DHist-demo](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html)

I added the following lines at the beginning to have the PyQt4-backend:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
```

My setup script looks like that:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

import os

base = 'Console'
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

options = {
    'build_exe': {

        # Sometimes a little fine-tuning is needed
        # exclude all backends except wx
        'includes': ['matplotlib', 'numpy.core._methods',
                     'matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg', 'numpy'],
        'excludes': [],
        'optimize': 2,
        'include_msvcr': True
    }
}

executables = [
    Executable('3Dhist.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='3Dhist',
      version='0.1',
      description='Sample matplotlib script',
      executables=executables,
      options=options
      )
```

cx-freeze runs correctly and creates all the necessary files. But the executable does not produce any output. It does something in the background, but it is not creating the graph window.

I know that everything works well outside the virtual environement with my full python installation.

This is the list of packages in my virtualenv:

- cx-Freeze (5.0.2)
- cycler (0.10.0)
- matplotlib (2.0.2)
- numpy (1.13.1)
- pip (9.0.1)
- pyparsing (2.2.0)
- PyQt4 (4.11.4)
- python-dateutil (2.6.1)
- pytz (2017.2)
- setuptools (36.2.7)
- six (1.10.0)
- wheel (0.29.0)

What am I doing wrong?